# Why index is not used after replacing "WHERE field=x" to "field in (x,y)"?

Tags: mysql, index

There is MariaDB 10.1.20.

1. Create table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE test2 (
      id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      flag enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
      KEY(id), KEY(flag)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
   ```
2. Index is used as usual:

   ```
   > EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id = 1;
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
   | id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
   |    1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | ref  | id            | id   | 4       | const |    1 |       |
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
   ```
3. But why index is not used here?

   ```
   > EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE id IN (1,2);
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   | id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   |    1 | SIMPLE      | test2 | ALL  | id            | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where |
   +------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   ```

Comment: Test with more rows in the table. Like a few thousands. Or a few million.

Answer (score 1):

- First, since the table is tiny (only 1 row?), you cannot trust `EXPLAIN` to give you information that will apply in a 'real' situation.
- Indexing a flag is rarely useful.  The Optimizer looks at the situation as says (roughly):  "If I need to scan more than 20% of the table, I won't bother using the index."  This is a reasonable decision because using an index requires bouncing between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.  Whereas, scanning the table sequentially is likely to be more efficient, in spite of having to check and throw out rows that are not needed.
- OK, `id` is not a flag.  But, to the optimizer it may as well be -- since you have only 1 row in your table?

Answer (score 0):

You have two things you can look at it.

- The Mona Lisa.
- A museum attendant that is pointing to the Mona Lisa.

You can't look at them both at the same time. Which do you want to look at it? That's the predicament the query planner is in. It knows there is only two options. And you're asking, why it is not looking directly at what you want to know? Why is it not asking the museum attendant first? That's a bit absurd though.

The museum attendant may be useful in guiding you where you need to go, but only if there is more than one thing to see.